# Poltergeist undefined method `write' when run rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rubygems, poltergeist

Why I am getting this whenever I run `bundle exec rspec`?

```
$ bundle exec rspec spec/features/schools_spec.rb --backtrace
Randomized with seed 31356
DEPRECATION WARNING: Dangerous query method (method whose arguments are used as raw SQL) called with non-attribute argument(s): "CONCAT_WS(' - ', schools.code, students.name) as student_school". Non-attribute arguments will be disallowed in Rails 6.1. This method should not be called with user-provided values, such as request parameters or model attributes. Known-safe values can be passed by wrapping them in Arel.sql(). (called from index at /home/touqeer/Desktop/school_system/app/controllers/schools_controller.rb:14)
DEPRECATION WARNING: NOT conditions will no longer behave as NOR in Rails 6.1. To continue using NOR conditions, NOT each conditions manually (`.where.not(:name => ...).where.not(:code => ...)`). (called from block in <class:Department> at /home/touqeer/Desktop/school_system/app/controllers/schools_controller.rb:12)
DEPRECATION WARNING: Dangerous query method (method whose arguments are used as raw SQL) called with non-attribute argument(s): "CONCAT_WS(' - ', schools.code, students.name) as student_school". Non-attribute arguments will be disallowed in Rails 6.1. This method should not be called with user-provided values, such as request parameters or model attributes. Known-safe values can be passed by wrapping them in Arel.sql(). (called from index at /home/touqeer/Desktop/school_system/app/controllers/schools_controller.rb:15)
DEPRECATION WARNING: NOT conditions will no longer behave as NOR in Rails 6.1. To continue using NOR conditions, NOT each conditions manually (`.where.not(:name => ...).where.not(:code => ...)`). (called from block in <class:Department> at /home/touqeer/Desktop/school_system/my/app/models/department.rb:12)
#<Thread:0x000000000bc38b50@/home/touqeer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/poltergeist-1.18.1/lib/capybara/poltergeist/client.rb:64 run> terminated with exception (report_on_exception is true):
Traceback (most recent call last):
/home/touqeer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/poltergeist-1.18.1/lib/capybara/poltergeist/client.rb:66:in `block in start': undefined method `write' for "/dev/null":String (NoMethodError)
Did you mean?  white
DEPRECATION WARNING: NOT conditions will no longer behave as NOR in Rails 6.1. To continue using NOR conditions, NOT each conditions manually (`.where.not(:name => ...).where.not(:code => ...)`). (called from block in <class:Department> at /home/touqeer/Desktop/school_system/app/models/department.rb:12)
.

Finished in 1 minute 54.93 seconds (files took 9.83 seconds to load)
6 examples, 0 failures

Randomized with seed 39118
```

It's not stoping anyting and test are working fine. But what is this?

Comment: Please include a full stack trace and output from rspec showing where this is triggered.

Comment: @anothermh I have updated the question, sorry forgot to infom you.